# Cannot override jwplayer css styles for chromecast icon

Tags: css, sass, jwplayer, chromecast

I want to style the chromecast icon in the JWPlayer skin to be a certain color, in the inspector, I can see the styles I need to override are: `--connected-color` and `disconnected-color`.

However, neither in the css nor through jquery can I override these colors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if those are classes or not, looks they are attributes so use [attributes selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[--connected-color] {
    // your css values here
}

[disconnected-color] {
    // your css values here
}
```

Or maybe you can find what you need in the [docs](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_reference/) :D

Comment: `--connected-color` is a style itself, not a class, I want to put the following code into my sass file, but it won't compile:

`.jw-icon-cast   
   button
     --connected-color: green;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a CSS preprocessor, like SASS or SCSS, make sure your linters are up-to-date! Sometimes this can prevent the CSS from compiling correctly.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.